# How to 'help' the compiler to deduce function template return type from a template parameter which is a function?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, template-argument-deduction

To de-clutter code from strtoxx calls, but still have them inlined, I would like to have a function template like:

```
template <typename STR_TO_NUM> static auto StrToNum( const string& s ) {
    char* pEnd;
    return STR_TO_NUM( s.c_str(), &pEnd, 10 );
}
```

And call it like

```
unsigned long x = StrToNum<strtoul>( "1984" );
```

However I get 'template argument deduction/substitution failed:' error. I can do:

```
template <typename T, T (*STR_TO_NUM)(const char *, char **, int)> static T StrToNum( const string& s ) {
    char* pEnd;
    return STR_TO_NUM( s.c_str(), &pEnd, 10 );
}
```

And specify the return type when calling. But it feels like that is redundant. Is there a way to avoid it?

I tried to 'template typedef' STR_TO_NUM using 'using' in C++11, but couldn't figure out how to do that for function types.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

`STR_TO_NUM` in your first example is a type. You pass `strtoul` that is a function. You can try something like:

```
template <typename STR_TO_NUM> static auto StrToNum( const string& s, STR_TO_NUM strToNum ) {
    char* pEnd;
    return strToNum(s.c_str(), &pEnd, 10 );
}
```

and call it as:

```
unsigned long x = StrToNum( "1984", strtoul );
```

Comment: to be `c++11` compliant you could help compiler deduce result type by `-> decltype(strToNum(s.c_str(), std::declval<char **>(), 10 ))`

Comment: Thanks. I meant to use strtoxx a value parameter and get the compiler to deduce everything from there. That way the compiler can inline strtoxx I believe.

Comment: As a pure guess: it's worth to try link-time optimisation (or whole-program optimisation), available in all major compilers and see if the function call is inlined despite pointer to a function.

Answer (score 2):

C++17 have:

```
template <auto STR_TO_NUM>
static auto StrToNum(const string& s) {
    char* pEnd;
    return STR_TO_NUM( s.c_str(), &pEnd, 10 );
}
```

instead of

```
template <typename T, T STR_TO_NUM>
static auto StrToNum(const string& s) {
    char* pEnd;
    return STR_TO_NUM( s.c_str(), &pEnd, 10 );
}
```

and its

```
StrToNum<decltype(&strtoul), &strtoul>("1984");
```